# Was Chiisana Obake Acchi, Kocchi, Socchi ever released in English?

Tags: chiisana-obake

When I was five or six years old, sometime around 1994, I pestered my mother to buy me a VHS tape about three little ghosts from the stand next to the checkout at the grocery store. I watched that video over and over again, then forgot about it until recently, when I remembered it, recalled how much the art style looked like early Pokemon, and suddenly realized that that was probably the first anime I ever saw.

In preparation to write an id request, I did some searching, and I now think the show I saw was probably [Chiisana Obake Acchi, Kocchi, Socchi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Ghosts,_There,_Here,_and_Where). The timeframe is right, the plot sounds similar, and the picture seems familiar. The character names listed for the Spanish and Polish dubs on [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1042) sound familiar and both Anime News Network and [My Anime List](http://myanimelist.net/anime/310/Chiisana_Obake_Acchi_Kocchi_Socchi) give the show the English title *Three Little Ghosts*. Anime News Network even lists English language script staff. But there's nothing under "English cast" or "English companies", and I can't find any hard evidence that it was actually released in the United States.

Was Chiisana Obake Acchi, Kocchi, Socchi ever released in the US, and if so, when and by whom?

Comment: [This article](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/TV+made+Saban+rich,+selling+falafels+makes+him+secure.-a012251839) suggests that [Saban Entertainment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saban_Entertainment), which was a US-based company that dubbed a number of Japanese anime (and also Power Rangers), co-produced "Three Little Ghosts" with a Japanese cooperator. This being the case, I can't imagine that they didn't also create a dub, but I can't find any concrete evidence of the dube existing either.

Comment: @senshin Good find, I'm pretty well convinced after seeing that article that this was the show I saw. Most anime from my childhood had been hacked apart by Saban on their way to the US, and a Google search suggests Saban often didn't credit their voice actors, so that could explain why there aren't any actors on ANN's page.

Comment: Not the most reliable, but [this TV Tropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NowWhichOneWasThatVoice) says it was common in early anime dubs to have uncredited voice actors, and specifically mentions Saban.

Comment: The show in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9cts_P1H0I) is definitely the one I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [article that senshin found](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/TV+made+Saban+rich,+selling+falafels+makes+him+secure.-a012251839) indicates that Saban Entertainment, the infamous anime mutilator and "creator" of Power Rangers, co-produced Chiisana Obake Acchi, Kocchi, Socchi, so it seems incomprehensible that they wouldn't have produced an English dub. I also found an [English-dubbed video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9cts_P1H0I) of Three Little Ghosts which I am quite sure is the show I saw. The [Anime News Network page](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1042) gives the three ghosts' English names as Sally, Bumper, and Cutter, which is exactly what I remember their names being in the show I saw. The ANN page doesn't list any English voice actors, but [this TV Tropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NowWhichOneWasThatVoice) mentions that Saban and other dubbing studios around this time frequently didn't credit the voice actors, so it's possible that the compilers of the ANN page couldn't find any information on the English voice actors and decided to leave it blank.

Given all that, I'm quite satisfied that Chiisana Obake Acchi, Kocchi, Socchi was released in the US and that it was the show I saw.